# Cannot import MPI from mpi4py in cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, mpi4py

I want to running my python code including mpi4py in a cluster.

I made my anaconda environment for mpi4py in the cluster and tested that the mpi4py is installed properly.

[image]

But, the cluster throw errors when it runs my code:

[image]

What happened on my job? The cluster has found mpi4py, but not MPI! I cannot understand this situation. Please can you give me a guide to make the cluster recognize the MPI setting? The cluster has slurm workload manager.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Terminal line called python3 from /opt/~~~ path.
Slurm called python3 from /home/user/.conda/~~~ path.

So, I should clarify the path of python in the conda env setting